# How to detect if any .exe file generating any error or in unresponsive state

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, executable

I have a window application, I run the app from the .exe file. Now I want to check if .exe file generates any error or check if app goes in unresponsive state for long or taking long time to complete the process in all the condition I would like to start the .exe again.

*Is there a way to achieve the aforementioned things using C# or any other way ?*

Answer (score 0):

A quick search led me to this page. [Detecting and automatically dumping hung GUI based windows applications](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ntdebugging/archive/2007/05/29/detecting-and-automatically-dumping-hung-gui-based-windows-applications.aspx)

Perhaps you'll get some ideas.